# Linux C USB write speed

Tags: c, linux, usb, raspberry-pi3

I am using a Raspberry Pi in order to communicate with a GSM/GPRS modem by USB. I am able to communicate in **115200bps**. I would like to improve the communication speed as much as possible but I do not know how I should do it. The connection is RPi's USB <--> Modem's USB

I am programming in C and I have to choose the `speed_t` in `cfsetispeed` and `cfsetospeed` functions, which it`s maximum is B230400...  I am using write function to send data.

USB 2.0 protocol has theoretically some mb/s speed so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: in your case, I suspect that is a "serial over usb". It's means that you access your modem through a emulated RS232 (serial) on USB connexion. So, you are limited to speed of RS232 connexion.

Comment: But if a connect a external pen drive, I am able to get much faster speed copying files. Does this mean that the usb port use different protocol depending on the application?

Comment: Not really no, it's a little more complicated... indeed, some device use a usb to serial converter to allow connexion with USB on computer but for device and driver it still a serial connexion, and so, you still configure communication with those kind of device like a serial one. It simplify hardware upgrade from serial to usb, which, some years ago, became mandatory because of the end of serial port on computer

Comment: In addition, usb still usb, you have a driver for usb to serial converter which in hidden and is between your driver and real usb

Comment: You should check if you have higher baud rates available. [The man page for `cfsetispeed()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cfsetispeed) says: "UNIX V7 and several later systems have a list of baud rates where after the fourteen values `B0`, ..., `B9600` one finds the two constants `EXTA`, `EXTB` ("External A" and "External B"). Many systems extend the list with **much higher baud rates** " (emphasis mine). [This Linux `termios.h` header](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5924bbecd0267d87c24110cbe2041b5075173a25/arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/termbits.h) goes to 4 megabit.

Comment: In addition to unwind's comment, if you change speed, be sure that your modem is configured to use this same speed

Comment: This is the modem, as you can see, it says that it has both usb and uart ports. It does not specify the baud rate of the USB port. https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/LISA-U2_DataSheet_(UBX-13001734).pdf

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not achieve higher rates.
Most of GSM/GPRS modem have inbuilt USB-->Serial(RS232) Converter.
The USB port is just for USB connector compatibility.
To communicate to these modem's from any computer you need to install drivers to **Emulate** a RS232 connection. 
In this case your board is already have those.
So basically you are doing a RS232 communication over USB lines. Your speed will be limited by RS232 standard baud-rates.

Comment: I would say that the modem's USB is an "oficial" usb connector. Have a look at: https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/LISA-U2_DataSheet_(UBX-13001734).pdf  2.5.2 section. I agree with the raspberry's usb-serial converter.